# view.getLayoutParams().width not working with nougat

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-7.0-nougat

I have written code to set height and width of view dynamically

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
view.getLayoutParams().height = 120;
```

It works perfectly with below nougat devices, but with nougat it is not working. It is just taking height and width as 0. Any changes after nougat update?

**Update :**

However it works

1) when i am using `view.requestLayout()` after setting height and width
2) `view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 120));`

So why it is working on pre nougat devices without using these 2 options?

Comment: Where are you using that code? Are you sure that the layout has already been drawn?

Comment: @GVillani82 It is inside `onGlobatLayout()` , so it will be called after view is created. I have used `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()`

Comment: view.requestLayout() is working for me thanks

Answer (score 11):

Try to call after setting `width` and `height`:

```
view.requestLayout()
```

Comment: Is it updated in nougat? because without calling `requestLayout()` also it is working on pre nougat devices

Comment: I'm not sure about nougat just some thought about changing params.

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 120));
```

or this

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 130;
params.width = 130;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

hope it helps you out

Comment: Thanks to you @Ravi Rupareliya for up vote... and welcome.